# Kestrel Time to connect takes long

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I have a .net core web api and it did respond slow (about 1000ms per request). I did put a stopwatch around the entire body of the ivoked method of the controller and it says: 1ms -- so where can the time go?

I invoked the API manually with a rest client and it says that *Time to connect* takes long. Any idea why this could be the case or how I can further investigate?

[image: kestrel time to connect]

Comment: Do you see this with every call? Or just the first one after launching the API?

Comment: I have this with _every_ call.